# Append image dimensions to src url | React

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have images being served from an API. We don't care what the initial raw size is however, I need to append a query to the end of the src url to resize the image to what we need.

The query looks like this: `?w=168&h=168`

The width and height values need to be dynamically set where ever the Image component is rendered. I was thinking of doing this via props however, how do you append the dimensions to the src prop?

Here is my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { classSet } from 'core/shared/utils';
import styles from './image.css';

const Image = ({ src, width }) => {
  const imageWidth = width / 2;

  return (<img className={classSet(styles.image, 'image')} src={src} style={{
    width: imageWidth,
    height: imageWidth
  }} />);
};

export default Image;
```

Here is the usage of the component:

```
<Image {...{ src: getImageFromAssets(assets), width: 336, dispatch, id }} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do you append the dimensions to the src prop?

The `src` prop expects a `string` argument. That's it.

**So to answer your question:**

```
<img className={classSet(styles.image, 'image')} src={src + `?w=${width}&h=168`} style={{
    width: imageWidth,
    height: imageWidth
}} />
```

just append to the original source string, another string!

Comment: Great idea however, how can I append dynamic dimensions that will be set via props where the image is used?

Comment: @Filth javascript has [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) that could help

Comment: yes I used them! I'll post the code that's solved it

Comment: @Filth when you can, please consider accepting my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution - many thanks to Rico for his guidance.

Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { classSet } from 'core/shared/utils';
import styles from './image.css';

const Image = ({ src, width, height }) => {
  return (<img className={classSet(styles.image, 'image')} src={`${src}?w=${width}&h=${height}`} width={width} height={height} />);

export default Image;
```

Usage:

```
<Image {...{ src: getImageFromAssets(assets), dispatch, id }} width={168} height={168} />
```